# NoClassDefFoundError on Calligraphy library

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-build

After adding `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.+'` to `build.gradle`, I had some conflicts on building my app, so I had to add **multiDexEnabled = true** to `defaultConfig` inside `build.gradle`. Those conflict are gone, but i got another exception (on opening the app) for the missing calligraphy library:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.R$attr
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig$Builder.<init>(CalligraphyConfig.java:150)
        at com.taxiyaab.android.util.ApplicationClass.onCreate(ApplicationClass.java:120)
        at newapp.com.taxiyaab.taxiyaab.PassengerApplication.onCreate(PassengerApplication.java:68)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4462)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My latest sdk build tools version is `22.0.1`. Has anybody faced this issue before?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you support API levels under 21, your `Application` class should extend `MultiDexApplication` from the support library.

```
class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

If you do not have a custom `Application` class, than you should add the MultiDexApplication class to your manifest directly

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>
```

See https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: thx for the answer , i did what you said , but it raise other exceptions , i think i shouldn't have to use multiDexEnabled.

Comment: i get : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2 , if doesn't use multiDexEnabled.

Comment: Did you get this exception while using MultiDexApplication? If no, which exceptions did it raise when you've used MultiDexApplication? Please supply the full exception details.

Comment: that exception raised because i think my app reach 65k function limit, so by enabling multidex its gone but my libraries need review to handle other exceptions because of enabling multidex config. anyway i accepted your answer , it was helpful thx.

Answer (score 7):

If your application extends from Application then override attachBaseContext inside Application i.e

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Also need to add dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer!

Answer (score 6):

Goodlife is here again to the rescue .
Add this line to ur java file that extends application.

```
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mInstance = this;

    //ADD MULTIDEX.INSTALL(THIS) SOLVED MY SIMILAR PROBLEM
    MultiDex.install(this);
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                    .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf")
                    .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                    .build()
    );
}
```

Comment: This worked, BUT, I had to move it before the setContentView as some of the layout files had calligraphy in them and broke the app. Once it was before the setContentView, things seem to be working just fine. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,update to multidex 1.0.2
and add Mulitidex.install(this) to the class extending application

Answer (score 0):

`MultiDex.install(this);`

This can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was too update the compiling library in app level gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

I updated it too

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and it worked fine for me.
Maybe this helps someone.