# Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hello I have problem runnig my app. I searched same topic but didnt understand that. I dont have classes with same name. Thank you for any help.This question could be duplicate but I wanted to show you my logs and my dependencies.

Updated again build.gradle and messages

```
        ==================build.gradle==============

        buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}




apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    // Google dependencies
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:+'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:+'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:+'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:+'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:+'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:+'
    // IBM Cloud jars
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.services:ibmdata:1.+'
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.services:ibmbluemix:1.+'
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.services:ibmfilesync:1.+'
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.services:ibmpush:1.+'
    compile 'com.ibm.mobile.services:ibmcloudcode:1.+'
    // Add another custom maven dependency here
    // *and/or*
    // Add any additional dependencies to your custom project by dropping them into the 'libs' directory
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            // Need Android Manifest to build
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            // BlueList Java code
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            // Your own code?
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            // More of your own code?
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            // Even more of your own code?
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']

            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

// The wrapper task allows the distribution of your software that can be built 
// with a quick call of 'gradlew' without the need to install gradle.
// NOTE: This can only be done if 'gradle wrapper' is called prior to distribution.
// See more info on the gradle wrapper here--> http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.10'
}

allprojects {
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

            ======================= gradle build ========================
            Information:Gradle tasks [:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:validateDebugSigning
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Information:Total time: 2.772 secs
Information:0 errors
Information:2 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

=============logcat=================
08-06 14:49:51.357  17153-17254/? E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-06 14:49:51.735  17177-17177/? E/GmsUtils﹕ Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
08-06 14:49:51.735  17177-17260/? E/GmsUtils﹕ Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
08-06 14:49:52.712  17153-17254/? E/LoginActivity﹕ A GoogleAuthException occurred. Please check your account credentials. Ensure your device's debug keystore SHA-1 fingerprint is configured for your 'Client ID for Android application'
08-06 14:49:52.906  17153-17254/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x7f760280 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f8fa4b8 arg=0x0
08-06 14:49:52.907  17153-17254/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x7f760280 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
08-06 14:49:53.109  17153-17254/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.ibm.bluelist, PID: 17153
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
            at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
            at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:599)
            at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.parse(GoogleIdToken.java:57)
            at com.ibm.bluelist.LoginActivity$GetTokenTask.validateTokenForProduction(LoginActivity.java:295)
            at com.ibm.bluelist.LoginActivity$GetTokenTask.validateToken(LoginActivity.java:269)
            at com.ibm.bluelist.LoginActivity$GetTokenTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:252)
            at com.ibm.bluelist.LoginActivity$GetTokenTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:200)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
08-06 14:49:55.307  17269-17269/? E/WifiManager﹕ mWifiServiceMessenger == null
08-06 14:49:55.683  17269-17292/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.b.c.<clinit>
08-06 14:49:55.685  17269-17292/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.ClientSessionContext', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.b.c.a
08-06 14:49:55.693  17269-17292/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.b.b.<clinit>
08-06 14:49:55.695  17269-17292/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLParametersImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.b.b.a
08-06 14:49:55.712  17269-17292/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.a.b.<clinit>
08-06 14:49:55.721  17269-17292/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.ssl.openssl.TicketEnabledOpenSSLSocketImplWrapper', referenced from method com.facebook.ssl.openssl.b.a
08-06 14:49:56.292  17269-17306/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x7f9ce328 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x80722728 arg=0x0
08-06 14:49:56.293  17269-17306/? E/NativeCrypto﹕ ssl=0x7f9ce328 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
08-06 14:49:58.477      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:49:58.478      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:49:58.479      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:49:58.480      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:49:59.814  17269-17269/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.facebook.push.adm.ADMBroadcastReceiver', referenced from method com.facebook.push.adm.a.b
08-06 14:50:08.490      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:50:08.492      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:50:08.494      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
08-06 14:50:08.497      224-224/? E/﹕ BatteryPropertiesListener: batteryStatus=5, batteryLevel=100, batteryVoltage=4355, batteryTemperature=340
```

Comment: defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579780/implementing-google-analytics-7-5-0-play-services-in-android-4-4-and-below-cra/31803004#31803004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these lines to your main project `build.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
}
```

and try again.

Comment: I added and it seems no change.

Comment: do clean and rebuild and again post log here if it is different.

Comment: ok it helped little. it take out this block  
:compileDebugJava
Note: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Downloads\Projekt\bluelist-auth-google-android\src\com\ibm\bluelist\LoginActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:preDexDebug
:dexDebug               
but the rest is still there.

Comment: you tried `multiDexEnabled true` inside `defaultConfig` ?  do clean build again @N.tsrg

Comment: I didnt. now there is 
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
inside andoid{ } in build.gradle

Comment: :collectDebugMultiDexComponents
:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex
:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents
:createDebugMainDexClassList FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':createDebugMainDexClassList'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
this is logs that seems to me now the problem

Comment: I have connected real android device and it logs permanently something and dont know how to stop it.

Comment: change `buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"` to `buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"` then clean and rebuild

Comment: dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}

Comment: Awesome now it worked. I first time asked on stackoverflow and didnt expect to work it this quickly. Just there is still Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android. and maybe it couses crashing my app during interacting with it.

Comment: Yes thank you. I added logcat could you look at it and say why it doesnt do what it suppose to do?@Anand Singh

Comment: check this `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76` so error is at 76th line of your code.