# Error on some devices - couldn't find class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz'

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android Custom Launcher. The application runs perfectly on some phones but do not start on others. On launching the application the following error occurs.

```
E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzv.zzaL

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzv
            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1651)
            at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1622)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5016)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4590)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4530)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1385)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:830)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:646)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi Aqib. Did you ever manage to find any information on why this was being thrown?

Comment: @mm8154 i have added my answer below.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

So after a lot of searching i came to know that this problem was due to the multidexing. On some phones multidexing don't work. May be due to their Android Version. However i fixed this by introductng an application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

and in menifest i entered the name in application tag like:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/xxxxxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:manageSpaceActivity="xxxxxxxxxx"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its save my day.

Comment: This helped me also and i would like to know why this helps?

Comment: This happens because of multi-dexing. When your code is so big that it can't be compiled with a single dex file, we use multidexing. But after that it wouldn't run on all phones.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my life

Comment: Thanks! your answer help me a lot!

Comment: What if I don't have multidex turned on, and still getting this error??

Answer (score 21):

+) Building Apps with Over 65K Method will cause this Error.

+) When your application and the libraries it references reach a certain size ( **DEX file** of your application can have total number of **methods upto 65,536** including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code), you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.

+) To resolve it, include **Multidex Configuration** in your ***build.gradle*** like the highlighted one in picture, along with this override the **attachBaseContext(Context base)** method in your Application class with the below content.

```
public class YourParentApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
 }
}
```

Add this in you Androidmanifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:name=".YourParentApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/radiius_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
```

For more information about Multidex refer these sites:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

[How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

[image]

Comment: The OP stated that he gets a runtime error, NOT a build error.  The solution you proposed only works for build errors.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky actually it DOES also fix the runtime error. Did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to multidexing, your application uses more than 64k methods update your

build.gradle(app level) with

defaultConfig{

.....

multiDexEnabled true

}

dependencies{

.....

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}

and

@Override

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

in your Application Class