# Android java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, verifyerror

I am attempting to launch my app on an Android device running 4.4.2.
Yet every-time I attempt to run, the error below appears:

```
02-24 22:23:30.421 18276-18276/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.android.app, PID: 18276
                                                   java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzt
                                                       at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5118)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4713)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:169)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Clicking through on the ContentProvider link, directs to below, but do not know where to go from here...

```
   public @Nullable AssetFileDescriptor openTypedAssetFile(@NonNull Uri uri,
            @NonNull String mimeTypeFilter, @Nullable Bundle opts) throws FileNotFoundException {
        if ("*/*".equals(mimeTypeFilter)) {
            // If they can take anything, the untyped open call is good enough.
            return openAssetFile(uri, "r");
        }
        String baseType = getType(uri);
        if (baseType != null && ClipDescription.compareMimeTypes(baseType, mimeTypeFilter)) {
            // Use old untyped open call if this provider has a type for this
            // URI and it matches the request.
            return openAssetFile(uri, "r");
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't open " + uri + " as type " + mimeTypeFilter);
    }
```

I have read it may have something to do with the versioning being out of sync.

The `build.gradle` file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" // 22.0.1

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
}
```

How can I alleviate this issue?

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35479999/3288182) help you