# In Android OS 4.x.x, I'm getting an uncaught exception saying 'Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzx'

Tags: android, google-play-services

Top level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

App module level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 15
    versionName "1.7.5"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

}
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("abc.keystore")
        storePassword "abc"
        keyAlias "abc"
        keyPassword "abc"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId = project.PRODUCTION_APPLICATION_ID
    }
    internal {
        applicationId = project.INTERNAL_APPLICATION_ID


    }
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
compile project(':mobihelp_sdk_android_v1.5.4')
compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:1.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'

compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
}
```

I have explored in google but didn't get any correct solution, can any one help me to resolve this issue. I have tired using the following code changes in application class. It didn't help me.

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(mContext);
}
```

Comment: I think this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196015/error-on-some-devices-couldnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-measurement) might provide the answer.

Comment: you can marked this thread as Answered by upvoting/accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this to close this thread:

Turns out this is a problem caused by [multidexing](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

This has been solved in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196015/error-on-some-devices-couldnt-find-class-com-google-android-gms-measurement) by using this class:

public class MyApplication extends Application {

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

}